# Does C#, Android, and SQLite work together?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I was trying to implement a system, where my C# program can insert value to SQLite database, and my mobile android application can retrieve the data in SQLite. Note that three of them are not located in the same PC. Can somebody tells me will it work conceptually?

P/S : I was new to C#, SQLite, and Android.

Comment: Why not? As long as the comms protocol you use is not platform specific, it should be fine. XML or JSON over HTTP (maybe SOAP, maybe REST) would simple platform-neutral mechanisms.

Comment: I was doubt on it because I read a book stating that SQLite is not a client/server database, thats why I was worried on it. Thanks for your kind advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the OP's comment:

> I read a book stating that SQLite is not a client/server database

SQLite is not "client/server" in that a program must access a SQLite database file directly through a SQLite driver, without the intermediary of a server (as is the case with MySQL/MSSQL/Oracle, for example). So both your C# and Android apps will need either network filesystem access to the SQLite database, or you'll need another program that does have filesystem access and that the two remote programs can talk to; to wit, you must write your own "server".

**Update:** To address your comment, no: I meant that those database systems already *have* a server, made to handle database requests from remote clients. SQLite doesn't - you access it by using the SQLite driver to interact with the database file directly; hence the need for filesystem access. So if your C# or Android app *cannot* access the SQLite file directly, you will need some intermediary program that can, and that program will have to talk to your C# and Android apps.

Comment: I was kind of stupid, so, did you mean that, the SQLite must work with either server(MySQL/MSSQL/Oracle) so that C# and Android apps can access to SQLite remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually it can work. You have to have your SQLite database hosted on a remote machine somewhere that both the C# application and the Android application can access from different places.

The great thing about databases is that they're not built to only work with a certain language. Any programming language that has, either built-in or through a third party, and way to connect to the type of database you're working with, can use it; however you have to be conscious of differences in operating systems. Two seemingly identical values transmitted from different OSes might look slightly different after being stored in your database. New line characters on Windows vs. Linux, for example, are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for you advices, it is useful to me.