# Regarding remote sqlite database connection

Tags: sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have sqlite database file on desktop PC.

And my C# application running on WinCE6.0 ported ARM9 core board.

Both,PC and Apllication board are in Network.

I want to connect my application to this Sqlite Database file.

Then tell me ,How to write the connection string to connect the remote sqlite database

file with my C# application which is running on WinCE ported ARM9 Board?

Best Regards, Mrudula Choudhhari

Answer (score 0):

Check this pages:

[How can I access SQLite with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906912/how-do-i-give-a-connection-string-to-a-server-on-a-network)

[New to remote database connection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465380/does-c-android-and-sqlite-work-together)

[SQLite.NET connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/sqlite-net-provider)

[Connection strings for SQLite](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite)

[[HowTo] Use SqLite ADO.NET with C#](http://www.ivankristianto.com/software-development/visual-studio-net/howto-use-sqlite-ado-net-with-c/943/)

Regards